# Why is my code not running nor prompting me for input?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I want to create a Java code that when receiving an array of any size it returns a version of that same array with all the 7's inside the array removed. The remaining elements should shift left towards the start of the array as needed, and the empty spaces at the end of the array should be 0.
I was trying create a method for the input of the array in which the array size is expanded if needed; the code I used for the input was this:

```
static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
public static int[] userInput() {

        int[] inputs = new int[5];
        int currentSize = 0;
        while (in.hasNextInt())
        { 
           if (currentSize > inputs.length)
           {
              inputs = Arrays.copyOf(inputs, 2 * inputs.length);
           }
          
           inputs[currentSize] = in.nextInt();
           currentSize++;
        }
        inputs = Arrays.copyOf(inputs, currentSize);
        return inputs;
    }
```

However; when I run the code, nothing happens, and it doesn't prompt me for input. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your code runs successfully. Did you write the code to execute that static method?

Here is a slightly modified version of your code.

I moved the `Scanner` to a try-with-resources to automatically close it. Make a habit of closing such resources you open. Any resource implementing `AutoCloseable` can be used within a try-with-resources.

I changed some names for clarity.

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        System.out.println( "running" ) ;
        int[] inputs = Ideone.userInput() ;
        System.out.println( Arrays.toString( inputs ) ) ;
    }

public static int[] userInput() {
try(
   Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in ) ;
 ) {
        int[] inputs = new int[5];
        int currentSize = 0;
        while ( scanner.hasNextInt())
        { 
           if (currentSize > inputs.length)
           {
              inputs = Arrays.copyOf(inputs, 2 * inputs.length);
           }
           inputs[currentSize] = scanner.nextInt();
           currentSize++;
        }
        inputs = Arrays.copyOf(inputs, currentSize);
        return inputs;
    }
}
}
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/mkwm7t).

For these inputs:

```
7
42
Exit
```

… we get this output:

```
running
[7, 42]
```

## `ArrayList`

Your code would be much simpler if using a `List` such as `ArrayList` rather than arrays. An `ArrayList` handles the resizing internally, with no effort from us.

If you are learning about manipulating arrays, very well. Or if you have massive amounts of data, use arrays as they are faster to execute while using less memory. But for day-to-day programming, use the Collections framework such as `List`.

```java
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        System.out.println( "running" ) ;
        List< Integer > inputs = Ideone.userInput() ;
        System.out.println( inputs ) ;
    }


public static List< Integer > userInput() {
try(
   Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in ) ;
 ) {
        List< Integer > inputs = new ArrayList<>() ;
        while ( scanner.hasNextInt())
        { 
           inputs.add( scanner.nextInt() ) ;
        }
        return List.copyOf( inputs ) ;
    }
}

}
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/d3lAS2).

To delete any value of seven, call `removeAll`.

```
boolean oneOrMoreRemoved = inputs.removeAll( List.of( Integer.valueOf( 7 ) ) ) ;
```